# How to use regular expression in subject name field in same code

Tags: javascript, jquery

$(function () {

```
$("#course_outline").validate({

    rules: {

        ignore: [],

        errorClass: "",

        course_code: {required: true},

        subject_name: {required: true},

        time_allocation: {required: true},

        lecturer: {required: true},

        subject_status: {required: true},

        agree: "required"

    },

    messages: {

        course_code: {required: "Course Code Mandatory"},

        subject_name: {required: "Subject Name Is Mandatory"},

        time_allocation: {required: "Time  is mandatory" },

        lecturer: { required: "Lecturer is mandatory" },

        subject_status: {required: "Subject Status is mandatory"},

        agree: "policy are acccept"
    }
});
```

});

i don't know to how to use regular expression in same code anybody help me soon.

accept: "[a-zA-Z]+".This method also i use but not working my script.

Comment: You can also add `pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"` attribute on `<input>`

Comment: Already i use this code but not working

Comment: Which one? HTML5 attribute? Did you try the code shown in the answers of the above original question

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lecturer"                                        id="lecturer"  placeholder="Lecturer"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" >